# get current user id with MySQL membership provider

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am referring to this tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs currently,but I am using MySql membership provider instead of sql membership provider. This is the code from tutorial :

```
protected void UserProfileDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

    // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
    e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
}
```

This is my code with error

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
    MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider currentUser = MySQLMembership.GetUser();

    // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
    e.Command.Parameters["@id"].Value = currentUserId;
}
```

My question is how to get currently logged on user id?
I have added mysql.web and mysql.data too. Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

To see user id you are logged with use `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`. To see all users currently logged use `show processlist;` or `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST`